# Почему не получается смешать прототип с другим объектом при помощи Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript

Есть такое определение класса:

```js
class Field {
    constructor(canvas) {
        const CANVAS = document.querySelector(canvas);
        const CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext("2d");

        return Object.assign(CONTEXT, Field.prototype); // *
    }

    prototypeMethodName() {
        return "something";
    }
}

console.log(new Field("canvas"));
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Я хочу, чтобы при вызове `new Field()` мне вернулся объект `CONTEXT`, к которому были бы примешаны другие методы, описанные в классе. То есть что бы `CONTEXT` содержал в себе все свойства, описанные браузером плюс мои свойства, описанные мной.

Но в итоге получаю "голый" `CONTEXT`, не содержащий моих свойств.

Почему-то у меня не получается заставить работать только вариант с прототипом, примешать `this` или какой-нибудь совершенно другой объект труда не составляет, а вот с прототипом прямо беда какая-то.

Подскажите, почему такой подход может не работать, и как заставить все это работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В поисках ответа задал [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854892/why-doesnt-merging-a-prototype-to-another-object-via-object-assign-work) на StackOverflow.

### Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855180/5899212):

> > Я хочу расширить его своими методами
>
> [Не стоит так делать.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) [По поводу этого в комментариях под ответом
>   мы немного подискутировали]
>
> > Но в итоге получаю "голый" CONTEXT, не содержащий моих свойств.
>
> Верно. Прототипы объектов не содержат перечисляемых свойств, поэтому
>   `Object.assign()` их и не находит. Взгляните в сторону новых
>   (добавленных в ES6) способ для итерации по объекту.

---

Короче говоря, все оказалось так, как я изначально и предполагал: свойства прототипа не являются перечисляемыми (enumerable), а с *не*перечисляемыми свойствами `Object.assign()` работать не может.